# Confusion in structure member alignment in 32 bit and 64 bit architecture

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel

I am facing some issue when running a 32bit application(Written in C) in a 64 bit linux kernel. The same application runs without any issues in 32 bit kernel.

After spending a lot time for debugging the picture became little more clearer. There is a structure shared between the userspace application and a kernel module. The values of members in the structure variable gets corrupted when passed from user space to kernel space.

Here is the defenition of the structure

```
struct entry
{
    unsigned active:1;
    unsigned strict:1;
    unsigned AB_is_ipv6:1;
    unsigned XY_is_ipv6:1;
    unsigned srtp_sideA_en:2;
    unsigned srtp_sideB_en:2;
    unsigned srtp_mki_sideA_en:2;
    unsigned srtp_mki_sideB_en:2;
    unsigned cnt_fdnat, cnt_fsnat, cnt_rdnat, cnt_rsnat;
    unsigned short Apt, Bpt, Xpt, Ypt;
    unsigned int err[2];
};
```

The values of the two bit fields srtp_mki_sideA_en and srtp_mki_sideB_en becomes corrupted frequently.

Is there any issue in sharing structure like this when there are bit field members inside it?

Is there any difference in the member alignment in 32 bit and 64 bit architecture that could result in memory corruption when sharing data structures?

Is there any other known issues when sharing data structures between 64 bit kernel and 32 bit applications?

Comment: If you print the size of the structure in the 64-bit kernel and the 32-bit program, is it the same? If not then you need to either pack the structure or add manual padding for alignment of the members that works on both 64 and 32 bits, or simply come up with a solution that doesn't require passing binary structures.

Comment: Bitfields is a very bad idea in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I would not trust the memory layout of that struct at all. It is not declared as packed, it has `int` and `short` parts in it, which are of different size for almost every architekture. Also the bitfields have compiler dependent catches to them (One compiler I used in the past allowed only 8 bit long bitfields).

I would totally reorganize the struct. First of all, order the contents by size (biggest first). Use packing, use types declared in stdint.h. `int32_t` for example is guaranteed to have 32 bits on every architecture.

If you do not have control over the struct and can not change it, reverse engineer the memory layout used by debugging, and then craft a struct in your application which resembles the given struct.